# Null response for spring-amqp Request/Reply Messaging

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm following the instructions for the `Stock Trading` sample, which outlines how to use request/reply messaging in `spring-amqp`: http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/sample-apps.html#d4e742

I've tweaked the sample instructions to create a client which should wait for the reply by using `convertSendAndReceive` instead of `convertAndSend`: https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/5774487

Now even though the reply is put on the responseQueue and I've updated the timeout `rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(60000);` to be longer than the 5 second default ... in my client I receive `null` back as the reply.

Does anyone know what's going on?

---

Update#1

I was advised to add a `<reply-listener/>` to the `<rabbit:template/>` but I'm not sure how to do that programatically:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyQueue(responseQueue());
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    // following is private
    //rabbitTemplate.addListener
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

Comment: I hope you aren't using spring 1.2.

Comment: I've tried both versions `<version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>` and `<version>1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>` for `org.springframework.amqp.spring-rabbit` ... but they both have the same behavior.

Comment: I'm not trying to answer your question. Spring is at version 3.2.3 right now, you really shouldn't be using outdated libraries.

Comment: Yup I'm on `3.1.x` based on the dependency hierarchy for `spring-rabbit` and I've got no inclination to jump upto `3.2.3` without having a good reason to do so. I think the docs URL may have thrown you off ... the doc url captures the version # of `spring-rabbit` and not spring itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the fact you are not getting an error on the `convertsendAndReceive` means that you have configured the `RabbitTemplate` with a fixed reply queue; if you do that, you need a listener container to receive the messages with the template as the 'listener'.

The easiest way to configure this is with xml

```
<rabbit:template ... reply-queue="foo">
    <reply-listener/>
</rabbit:template>
```

I suggest you get it working first without a fixed reply queue - let the template create its own reply queue.

You should also remove the `MessagePostProcessor` in the `convertSendAndReceive` because the template will take care of its own reply queue and correlation configuration. This is not allowed when there's not a fixed reply queue.

When you switch to using a fixed reply-queue I suggest you use 1.2.0.M1 (or snapshot) because the template used a non-standard correlation technique.

**Update:** To use @Bean configuration instead of XML simply create a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` bean and make its listener the `RabbitTemplate`. Just be sure to use the same queue in both places (the parser takes care of that when using the namespace).

Comment: Thanks Gary I started using `1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` this morning ... but its super important to me that I get the response back where I've called `convertsendAndReceive` ... if I configure a `<listener>` then the MessageListenerAdapter will let the POJO which implements `handleMessage` take control of the flow ... which is nowhere around the code block that calls `convertsendAndReceive` ... or am I misunderstanding you? Is `<reply-listener/>` different from `<listener/>`?

Comment: Gary I'm staring at `TemplateParser` which configures `<reply-listener/>` off of the xml file on line 109 but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this programmatically in a `@Configuration` file instead of in the xml file ...could you please have a peek at the update in my answer and comment on this?

Comment: You simply need to declare a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` where the `messageListener` property is the `RabbitTemplate` that is to receive the replies.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit turned around, I thought I had to set a property on `RabbitTemplate` but now I understand that its the other way around.

Comment: BTW neither having nor removing `MessagePostProcessor` in `convertSendAndReceive` made a difference in how the request/reply operated ... maybe because i have a fixed queue for responses ... so i took your advice and removed it alltogether.

Comment: Since you seem to be part of the spring foundation, would you mind updating the docs Gary? http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply could afford to give the `@Configuration` equivalent of the applicationContext.xml stuff. Here are my notes on this: https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/5776671

Comment: Would you mind opening a 'Documentation' JIRA issue? https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP